# bulk copy throws an exception when there is a DateTime column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, columnmappings

i am doing a bulk copy in c#, and its working fine except when i add a DateTime column to the DataTable the bulk copy throws an exception that `The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination.` , when i remove the DateTime column and execute the bulk copy things work normally

is there something extra i have to do when adding a DateTime column?

Comment: DateTime.MinValue\MaxValue don't fit SQL DateTime. Make sure you don't insert this values. Use nullable DateTime? in C# code instead to specify no-date value.

Comment: Are you sure with the case sensitivities? Check the column names between database and datatable

Comment: Are you sure the date\time column is available in the target table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience the below are the possibilities to cause this kind of issues

1. Column names match in source and table That the column types match
2. Allow nulls in date\time columns in your table, then insert the null value through DataTable, If it works then the problem with data else mapping is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be specifically due to it being a DateTime column - check your ColumnMapping names as they are case sensitive - that could be the problem.

Blogged about it [here](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/04/sqlbulkcopy-columnmappings-mismatch.html)

Comment: as i said, as soon as remove the DateTime column from the mapping things work

Comment: But does it then copy that column into the destination table...?